# Ionic Make Ion-header-bar appear above Ion-Side-Menu

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm using the Ionic framework and I just got the template project side-menu from them. I was wondering if it's possible to put the ion-header-bar appear above the ion-side-menu.

This is how it is right now:

[image: Right now]

This is how I want it to be:

[image: Ideal]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could use an alternative drawer component for your side menu, for example:

https://github.com/beaver71/ionic-ion-drawer

Basic usage is:

```
<drawer side="left">
    <ion-content>
     ....
    </ion-content>
</drawer>
```

Here is a working example: http://codepen.io/beaver71/pen/BKpRjM/